# RxJava multiple subscribeOn() in chain

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'd like to know what happens when we have multiple `subscribeOn()` methods in a RxJava chain. For instance if I had a chain that was something like this,

```
    Single.fromCallable { repository.apiCall1() }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap { result -> Single.fromCallable { repository.apiCall2() } }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { // do something }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.ui())
```

would this mean that the thread the API calls run on is not the same? And what would be the impact / effect of removing the first `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` call in this chain above?

Appreciate any insights on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks it wont have any effect. It doesn´t matter where you put the `subscribeOn` in the chain that will have the same effect.

As per documentation, `observeOn` has a different behaviour, so you can change the thread where you´re observing the result at any point in the chain.

From the Rx documentation:

> the SubscribeOn operator designates which thread the Observable will
>   begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators
>   that operator is called. ObserveOn, on the other hand, affects the
>   thread that the Observable will use below where that operator appears.
>   For this reason, you may call ObserveOn multiple times at various
>   points during the chain of Observable operators in order to change on
>   which threads certain of those operators operate.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html

Comment: hmm.. what does that mean for the other `subscribeOn()` calls? (would they just create another thread un-necessarily for nothing). Is there some way to test only one thread is actually being created / used?

Comment: It will use the thread of the first `subscribeOn` of the chaining call.
You can check an example in this article (*subscribeOn() gotchas* section):
https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea